# Vaadin create modal Dialog window

Tags: java, user-interface, window, vaadin

How can I create a modal dialog window in Vaadin 7.x? I've already found out that I have the main window and add to this my new dialog window, but how can I get the main window? I want to reach it from a View.

```
getApplication().getMainWindow()
getWindow()
```

none of them works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends which is your main class.
From a normal UI-inherited class you can just use addWindow(...) to add a dialog(subwindow) to the UI.

```
public class MyApplication extends UI
{

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
    {
        addWindow(new ModalWindow());
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it works! I didn't try addWindow() (I don't know why.. :) )
Just one more tip: if you are not in main class then 
UI.getCurrent().addWindow() will work perfectly.